# Вывод ОЗУ отдельного приложения winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ram

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] pr = Process.GetProcessesByName("Form1");
        foreach (Process process in pr)
        {
            string memory = Convert.ToString(process.WorkingSet64 / 1024);
            label1.Text = memory;
        }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'label1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."

Спустя время данный код выдает ошибку (каждый раз в разное время, иногда в начале, иногда поработает немного). 
Нужно узнать потребление ОЗУ и обновлять в реальном времени пока работает прога. Столкнулся с еще одной проблемой - показывает общее потребление ОЗУ, а не отдельного приложения.

Вердикт - я не знаю как доработать этот код и я запутался. Дошло до того, что у меня кое как работает если продублировать код в 2 методах))). Но это бред, так что хотелось бы вашей помощи с этим вопросом. Вывод ОЗУ отдельного приложения (не обязательно Form1, хочется, чтобы можно было выбрать там браузер и тд, но этим я уже сам займусь.)

Comment: Как Вы этот код вызываете? В каком потоке это делаете?

Comment: В методе Timer1_Tick если вы про это. Если не про это - то я не знаю хд)

Comment: Какой из такмеров вы используете? Dispatcher Timer? В каком потоке ваш таймер вызывает свой обработчик?

Comment: Нет, не dispatcher

Comment: System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
timer.Interval = 1000; 
timer.Start(); сразу после инициализации компонентов

Comment: Я кажется разобрался

Comment: [Timer Класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) - `System.Threading.Timer: выполняет один метод обратного вызова в потоке пула потоков через регулярные интервалы.` - `в потоке пула потоков`, вам надо либо весь таймер в UI потоке вызывать (то есть использовать DispatcherTimer, либо только лайбл обновлять в UI потоке через дипетчер или через Invoke метод формы\любого контрола)

Comment: Используйте [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8), он предназначен специально для работы в UI и вызывает обработку тика в правильном потоке, а именно в потоке UI. Из постороннего потока взаимодействие с компонентами UI невозможно.